# subdomain including htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a subdomain code.domain.com that redirects to domain.com/code

I want to redirect for example: code.domain.com/hello/world.html to domain.com/code/?path=hello/world.html

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^code/(.+)$ http://domain.com/code/?path=$1
```

But I am not sure what is wrong with it, it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Rewrite rules can be so confusing. :) Lucky Apache uses PCRE regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use these rules in the root directory htaccess file (not the code directory) (you can also point the code.domain.com to the root directory instead if you want) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^code.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /code/?path=$1
```